# If $f$ is entire and $f(3/n) = 6- \frac{10}{n} - \frac{20}{n^2}$, then find $f$ in explicit form.

Tags: complex-analysis

I’m not really sure where to start with this problem. I think I might have to use something about the fact that all the zeroes of $f$ are isolated since it’s entire, but i’m not sure. Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First note that there's an "obvious" function that takes those values at $\frac{3}{n} \colon n \in \mathbb{N}$. You can work out what what that function should be with a bit of clever rearrangement. Let's call this function $g(z)$ and note that it is entire.

Then $f(z)-g(z)$ is an entire function that is zero at each $\frac{3}{n} \colon n \in \mathbb{N}$ (and also at $0$, by continuity). Using the result that you mentioned, $f(z)-g(z)$ is an entire function with non-isolated zeros so is zero everywhere.

Thus $g(z)$ is the only possible function satisfying this property.

Comment: How do we know that the zeros of $f$ and $g$ are non-isolated?

Comment: Not the zeroes of $f$ and $g$: the zeroes of $f-g$. And we know that there's non-isolated zeroes because one of them is at $0$ and others are at $3/n$ tending to $0$.

Comment: Right, mistype there. So we're just saying that the zero at 0 is non-isolated, right? How do we know there's a zero at 0?

Answer (score 2):

You may write $$f(\frac 3 n) = 6 - \frac{10} 3 \cdot \frac 3 n - \frac{20} 9 \left(\frac 3 n\right)^2.$$ This means that, if you define the polynomial function $g(z) = 6 - \frac{10}3 z - \frac{20}9 z^2$, then you have $f(z) - g(z) = 0$ for $z = \frac 3 n$.

Do you know a theorem that allows you to conclude?